# How to set method level timeout for selenium test methods using @ tags. by overriding the framework level timeout

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, junit4, junit-rule

I need to override the existing framework level timeout set for all the test scripts as,

```
    @Rule
public Timeout timeout;
public String methodTimeout = null;
```

The default timeout for all the tests is set as 10 mins (Each tests will run for max 10 mins, after that test will get timeout).

Some tests will run for more than 10 mins. In this case the default timeout will kill the browser and the test gets failed.

Am using selenium java with junit, and using Page Object model.

Could anyone help me on this to override the existing timeout.

Note : The framework was developed by dev team.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout for every test using @Test annotation and timeout property. Check the JUnit api and provided example [@Test](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html).

Comment: Test level annotation can be used if Timeout Rule is not implemented in framework level. Its clearly given in junit doc https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests

Comment: My tests suggests that timeout in @Test annotation overrides global Timeout rule.

Comment: Timeout rule is in TestBaseClass. 
I have used an additional tag to give method level timeout in every test method. I got the timeout value from the tag to a startup class.
Test base class is calling a method from startup class. how to set the timeout value which is got from the test  level tag to the testbaseclass.

Comment: Am able to print the timeout value got from the new tag. Its not overriding the Timeout rule

Answer (score 0):

You can define timeout value for specific @Test

> @Test(timeout = 120000)